# Find incremental x amount of numbers in range

Tags: algorithm, increment

I don't even know how to explain this... I've been looking for algos but no luck.

I need a function that would return an array of incrementally bigger numbers (not sure what kind of curve) from two numbers that I'd pass as parameters.

Ex.:

```
$length = 20;
get_numbers(1, 1000, $length);
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 200, 500... // let's say that these are 20 numbers that add up to 1000
```

Any idea how I could do this..? I guess I'm not smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: Why those numbers specifically and not e.g. 1,2,3,...,20?

Comment: That's just an example, I just want the numbers to go up incrementally, with a pretty steep curve.

Comment: If you're not married to "round looking" values, looks like you could use an exponential curve. You've got to find some number X such that  X^length==1000. Then you create a list of [X^0, X^1, X^2... X^length]. I'm not sure how to solve for X, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an exponential curve? Sample Python implementation:

```
begin = 1
end = 1000
diff = end - begin
length = 10
X = diff**(1.0/(length-1))
seq = []
for i in range(length):
    seq.append(int(begin+X**i))
print seq
```

(note: `**` is the Python operator for exponentiation. Other languages may or may not use `^` instead)

Result:

```
[2, 3, 5, 10, 22, 47, 100, 216, 464, 999]
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! That looks nice. If I change 1.0 with something would the curve change, I guess..?

Comment: Yeah, it will stretch or squash the curve. Replacing 1.0 with 2.0, for example, will cause the numbers to go up to only 500 instead of 1000. And replacing it with 0.333 will cause the numbers to go up to 3000 instead of 1000.